# Contagem da reputação do dia diferente da contagem da medalha

Tags: suporte, medalhas, reputação

Às vezes acompanho a contagem da reputação em relação à medalha e percebo que neste caso da medalha de prata "Épico" a contagem é sempre menor do que recebi de reputação no dia como ilustra a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste caso, há uma diferença de `15pts` a menos na contagem da medalha. Alguém sabe porquê isso ocorre?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Creio** (não estou bem certo) que votos de **respostas aceita** e **recompensas** não são contados como reputação para essas medalhas, pois estão isentos do [limite diário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), ou seja para contar nos 200 limites diários, somente a reputação que vier de upvotes.

O "200 de reputação" que ele se refere é o mesmo valido sobre outra medalha, chamada Capelo (no "original" `mortarboard`):

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard

Conforme o link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation:

> ... Apenas as gratificações recebidas e as respostas aceitas não estão sujeitas ao limite diário de reputação...

Então como daqueles 25:

- 10 eram de um upvote
- 15 resposta aceita

Só o upvote foi contabilizado para as medalhas:

- Capelo (Ganhou 200 ou mais pontos de reputação (o limite diário) em um dia - provavelmente você já tenha esta)
- Épico (Ganhou 200 de reputação em um dia 50 vezes)
- Legendário (Ganhou 200 de reputação em um dia 150 vezes)

---

Teste efetuado:

[image: medalha legendário]

Veja que mostra que hoje até agora (20:55 - 11/05/2018) eu ganhei 85 pontos, mas no acompanhamento da medalha me mostra `70/200`.

Conforme a imagem também é possível notar que eu tive uma pergunta com resposta aceita, o que totaliza 15, sendo que este +15 eu ganhei a 7 horas atrás, no entanto o +10 do upvote eu ganhei a apenas 3 horas, mas parece que ele já foi contabilizado.

Ou seja, se fosse problema de algum JOB (algo como um sincronizador) citado na [resposta do Renan](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7061/3635), os +15 deveriam no minimo terem sido contabilizados juntos ao +10 de upvote que recebi depois, mas isto não ocorreu.

Isto me leva a crer que sim, as medalhas funcionam conforme o *limite diário* e *respostas aceitas* assim como *recompensas ganhas* não serão contabilizados.

Answer (score 1):

Votos de recompensas e de aceite contam para a obtenção dos 200 votos diários.

[Bounties and Epic/legendary progress](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163271/221728)

Os contadores das medalhas são atualizados por jobs. Esses jobs rodam de tempos em tempos. A depender da medalha e da carga do sistema, pode levar até um dia para que os números sejam atualizados. Quase sempre demora menos... Espere algumas horas e veja de novo.

Comment: Desculpe Renan, não leve a mal, eu fiz um teste em minha conta mesmo e acho que depende sim do limite diário, a não ser que exista um bug muito absurdo no sistema do site, veja o teste https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7060/3635 - ps: espero que não leve a mal. ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sem problemas :) agora, eu tô me baseando neste post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165605/221728

Comment: Renan, entendo que o link afirme isto, no entanto é uma postagem de 2013, pode ser que mudaram algo no "ecossistema", pode ser que se confundiram, estou a 5 dias seguidos fazendo várias prints e acompanhando a medalha, esse é de hoje: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfBpW.png --- todos os dias que ganhei no minimo um *"aceite"* não apareceu nada, mas é só ganhar um upvote e em pouco tempo aparece, estava a 60/100, logo ganhei um upvote e foi em pouco tempo para 70/100. Nos ultimos dias acompanhei durante 8 horas em médias respostas aceitas, mas o progresso da medalha não mudou em nenhum dos casos.